# React JS with Redux: How to pass e.target.value from one component to another

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an input select that generated a value using an onChange method. However, I am trying to pass the selected value from this component to another component. This is how my code looks like now:

```
 <Input type="select" name="selectInput" value={this.state.completeTask} onChange=. 
 {this.handleChangeCompleteTask} >
        <option value="" disabled> Select Reason</option>
        <option value="Task Completed"> Task Completed</option>
        <option value="Task in Progress"> Task in Progress</option>
 </Input>
```

The handleChangeCompleteTask is:

```
handleChangeCompleteTask = (e) => {
    this.setState({ completeTask: e.target.value });
};
```

I also have an initial state for completeTask as:

```
   state = {
        completeTask: ''
    };
```

The question is how can I pass completeTask current state as in `this.state.nonCompletionReason` and pass it to a different function in a different component.

The other component has a function that handles tasks as in:

```
handleTasks = (tasks) => {
 this.props.tasks(tasks)
}
```

I would like to pass the

Comment: share code where you want to show this information? what is the relationship between this component and other component?

Comment: The other component has a function that would ideally take this e.target.value state as a parameter. I will update that.

Comment: Can you share that minimal code?

Comment: Yes, it has been updated...

Answer (score 0):

You will want to pass `state.completeTask` into the props of the other component like this: `<OtherComponent completeTask={this.state.completeTask} />`. Then the `OtherComponent` will have access via `this.props.completeTask`.